# NginX 0.9.6 Frustrating Compile Issues Ubuntu/GCC 4.6.1

Tags: gcc, nginx, compilation

Today I've been working on setting up extra VPS clones and I've run into a strange and frustrating compile time error with the latest nginx development version (0.9.6).

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS x86_64, however, I've upgraded GCC to 4.6.1.  ***./configure*** runs without errors, but upon running ***make -j4*** I'm presented with the following error:

> > gcc -c -pipe  -O -W -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-function -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Werror -g  -I src/core -I src/event -I src/event/modules -I src/os/unix -I objs \
> >                     -o objs/src/core/ngx_open_file_cache.o \
> >                     src/core/ngx_open_file_cache.c
> >     src/core/ngx_resolver.c: In function
> >     'ngx_resolver_process_ptr':
> >     src/core/ngx_resolver.c:1425:43:
> >     error: variable 'qclass' set but not
> >     used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
> >     src/core/ngx_resolver.c:1425:36:
> >     error: variable 'qtype' set but not
> >     used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
> >     cc1: all warnings being treated as
> >     errors
>
> make[1]: ***
>   [objs/src/core/ngx_resolver.o] Error 1
>   make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished
>   jobs.... make[1]: Leaving directory
>   `/root/nginx-0.9.6' make: *** [build]
>   Error 2

(Better seen at pastebin: http://pastebin.com/g0bNS2nY)

I've tried adding --with--cc-opt="-W" to the ./configure options but without result.  Can anyone please shed some light on this show stopper?

Many, many thanks in advance!

Comment: Well yes, this is a Release Candidate for gcc-4.6.0. And BTW, 4.6.0 has been released four days later.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A nicer way to do this is to pass the following to ./configure

```
--with-cc-opt=-Wno-error
```

Comment: This worked really well when my nginx compile started throwing `src/core/nginx.c:1118: warning: unused parameter ‘cmd’` errors.

Answer (score 4):

Edit the `Makefile`, remove `-Werror`. That options means: quit the compiler immediately if something doesn't seem right. Or run the compile command that went wrong manually, again without the `-Werror` flag:

```
gcc -c -O -W -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-function \
 -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -g  -Isrc/core -Isrc/event \
 -Isrc/event/modules -Isrc/os/unix -Iobjs \
 -o objs/src/core/ngx_open_file_cache.o src/core/ngx_open_file_cache.c
```

Comment: Thank you - for anyone else with this problem run your ./configure options then afterwards edit the generated objs/Makefile and remove the -Werror switch.  Running make -j4 worked like a dream afterwards!

Comment: @Peter: does this package really put `-Werror` in its production build settings?